# Возможно ли использовать template<typename T> или template<class T> в модульном подходе в qt с gcc?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, gcc

Возможно ли разбить реализацию шаблонного класса на .h и .cpp? Работаю в Qt Creator, использую компилятор gcc. При попытке разбить реализациюю cpp файл не видит класс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По состоянию на сегодня - можно только если вы заранее знаете, с какими типами нужно будет инстанцировать ваш класс, и потребуете в .cpp-классе, чтобы это инстанцирование было выполнено.

Неудобно, неэффективно...

Если ну прямо никак не можется и позарез надо отделить одно от другого - тогда в одном заголовочном файле сделайте объявление, а реализацию - в другом заголовочном же файле, который включается `#include` в нужном месте в первый...

В свое время пробовали, даже в стандарт, если не ошибаюсь, вносили такую возможность - реализацию отделять, но выяснилось, что овчинка выделки не стоит...